# Piping stream from busboy to request post

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, express, multipartform-data

I have `multipart/form-data` that I am posting to an express endpoint `/data/upload`, form markup below:

```
form(enctype="multipart/form-data", action="/data/upload", method="post")
  input(type="file", name="data")
```

I'm using `busboy` to read the file stream, which is working fine.  From there, I want to send the stream again as `multipart/form-data` to a second Java backend, using the `request` npm module.  JS client/Java server code below:

```
  req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, fileStream, fileName, encoding, mimeType) {

    var reqBody = {
      url: server.baseURL + 'api/data',
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      formData: {
        file: fileStream
      }
    };

    request.post(reqBody, function (err, r, body) {
      // Do rendering stuff, handle callback
    });
 });
```

**Java endpoint (api/data)**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void addData(FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart) {
  // Handle multipart data here      
}
```

I don't think I'm sending the file correctly as `multipart/form-data` here... but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to essentially pipe the stream from `busboy` directly to `request` without reading/writing from a temp file on the client-side.  Any ideas?

**Java stack trace:**

```
Apr 27, 2016 5:07:12 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * Server has received a request on thread qtp1631904921-24
3 > POST http://localhost:8080/api/data
3 > Connection: keep-alive
3 > Content-Length: 199
3 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------331473417509479560313628
3 > Host: localhost:8080

Apr 27, 2016 5:07:12 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 3 * Server responded with a response on thread qtp1631904921-24
3 < 400

17:07:13.003 [qtp1631904921-24] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser parseNext - bad HTTP parsed: 400 No URI for HttpChannelOverHttp@425137da{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
```

**Rahat's recommended change**:

```
 31     var reqBody = {
 32       url: server.baseURL + 'data',
 33       headers: {
 34         'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 35         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
 36       }
 37     };
 38 
 39     req.pipe(req.busboy.pipe(request.post(reqBody)));
```

**Threw error:**

```
Error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.
   at Busboy.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:154:22)
```

Comment: You are re-defining `req`. Is that intended?

Comment: It's a poor choice of variable name, but it's not a problem.  I'll change it in the post above.

Comment: Have you looked into piping your `busboy` to your java endpoint?

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or link to documentation?  Thanks--

Comment: Please add stack trace of java exception

Comment: Something like `req.pipe(busboy).pipe(request.post(url))`

Comment: @Ilya Stack trace added

Comment: Rahat I tried your code, seems like there's an issue with chaining the streaming... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098400/how-to-chain-write-stream-immediately-with-a-read-stream-in-node-js-0-10

Comment: File is a ReadableStream. So, how about this: `fileStream.pipe(request.post(url))`

Comment: Hm.  Slightly different (albeit similar) error thrown. 

`5 > POST http://localhost:8080/api/data
5 > Connection: keep-alive
5 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data
5 > Host: localhost:8080
5 > Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Apr 27, 2016 5:22:42 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 5 * Server responded with a response on thread qtp1991537156-17
5 < 400`

Comment: There is no enough information in the log. Can you set log level to debug or even more detailed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to provide 'Content-Length' for the multipart upload manually, because [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) (and underlying [`form-data`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data)) can't figure it out by themselves.
So request sends invalid Content-Length: 199 (the same for any incoming file size), which breaks the java multipart parser.

There are multiple workarounds:

1) Use incoming request 'Content-Length'

```
request.post({
  url: server.baseURL + 'api/data',
  formData: {
    file: {
      value: fileStream,
      options: {
        knownLength: req.headers['content-length']
      }
    }
  }
}, function (err, r, body) {
  // Do rendering stuff, handle callback
})
```

This will produce a bit incorrect request though, because incoming length includes other upload fields and boundaries, but busboy was able to parse it w/o any complaints

2) Wait until file is completely buffered by the node app then send it to java

```
var concat = require('concat-stream')
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldName, fileStream, fileName, encoding, mimeType) {
  fileStream.pipe(concat(function (fileBuffer) {
    request.post({
      url: server.baseURL + 'api/data',
      formData: {
        file: fileBuffer
      }
    }, function (err, r, body) {
      // Do rendering stuff, handle callback
    })
  }))
})
```

This will increase app memory consumption, so you needed to be careful and consider using [busboy limits](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#busboy-methods)

3) Buffer file to disk before uploading (just for the reference)

- [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) + [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) - I recommend using express for webservers, it makes things more manageable, and multer is based on the busboy
- [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

Comment: Just tried it- seems to work.  Thank you so much for taking the time to write this up.  I'll award bounty as soon as it lets me.

Comment: You are welcome! Another lib that may be useful for your case (node - java integration) - is https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy to proxy some requests to java directly, plus I'd suggest to take a look at https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent as a replacement for 'request' - it has more clear syntax and can run on both browser and backend.

Comment: In my tests 2 still does not works for some small files. Consider send a custom header with exact file size, which could always be read before stream start.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, send a custom header with exactly size file (bytes). The header always can be read before handle payload stream. Use this instead of content-length header of previous answer, because that sometimes doesn't works (with small files, i guess, but i cannot ensure that works with large files).

Answer (score 0):

For the answer of Afanasii Kurakin

```
request.post({
  url: server.baseURL + 'api/data',
  formData: {
    file: {
      value: fileStream,
      options: {
        knownLength: req.headers['content-length']
      }
    }
  }
}, function (err, r, body) {
  // Do rendering stuff, handle callback
})
```

You should change from `req.headers['content-length']` to the real file size, normally the content-length from header is bigger than the file size. I got pain because of the content-length and after using the file size, everything worked perfectly.